# Android back softkey how to use

Tags: android, back-button, back

I have a short question:

I'm new in the worl of android and I started now to programm a little app.
Now I have finished it and debugged it on my Samsung Galaxy S3. The application has 4 layouts. With a button you go to the next layout. So, I will, that if when I press the back softkey on my device, that it goes back to the last layout (like from layout 4 to layout 3).
When I tested it on my device, it always closes the app if I press the back softkey.

What can I do, that by pressing the app will change to the previous layout and closes if I press the back softkey if the main_actity is showed?

Thanks a lot for every answer.

With best regards

Comment: by default when you press back button current activity is popped from back stack , destroyed and previous activity in the stack takes focus

Comment: How are you changing layouts?

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "new layout" should be a new activity/Fragment. Nothing else

Period

Do not try to change this behaviour.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: "What you call a "new layout" should be a new activity. Nothing else" -- well, it could be fragments, added to the back stack via fragment transactions.

Comment: Houps my keyboard forgot to write ;-) Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to the back press in the Activity's `onBackPressed()` callback. Please be careful that whatever you do makes sense from the user's perspective. Going back one "page" in your view hierarchy and closing the app after all that seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

By your sayings, you want the back button to navigate between layouts. However the back button navigates through activities.
If you need the back button to do something else than navigating through activies, you have to include it in `onBackPressed()` method. For instance, if you want to move from layout2 to layout1 you an do this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //do something to hide layout2 and show layout1.
        //You can use View.visibility or anything!    
    }
```

> This is one of the plenty solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You should enter these codes in current activity to goto wantedActivity when press back on your device :

```java
onBackPressed()
{
startActivity(new(Intent(currentActivity.this , wantedActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: You should only do this if you want to override the default (and normally most intuitive) behaviour. It's wrong to assert its use in all cases, and it does not apply to this question.